# how can I create an array based some fields in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

eg: the input is

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e79ae1c11344b2895797042"),
    "startDay" : "20200312",
    "endDay" : "20200314"
}
```

I want to get ['20200312','20200313','20200314']. What should I do ?

Comment: Do the numbers increment by 1. Do you want to store the array as a field in the document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used [$range](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/range/) which returns `Array` of numbers between range
and [$range](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/range/) accepts only **integers**. So, I convert the **String** values of `startDay` and `endDay` to integers using [$toInt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toInt/)

Try this query,

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "days": {
        "$range": [
          {
            "$toInt": "$startDay"
          },
          {
            "$add": [
              {
                "$toInt": "$endDay"
              },
              1
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Query Result

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5e79ae1c11344b2895797042"),
    "days": [
      20200312,
      20200313,
      20200314
    ]
  }
]
```

[Query Test](https://mongoplayground.net/p/1lsUkfoMa36)